# How can I change config files for my server in the docker setup?

Tags: docker, azerothcore

I have an [AzerothCore Docker setup (standard)](https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Install-with-Docker).

How can I access to local files in order to change my server's configuration?

I searched a bit but I couldn't find any volumes. And when we attach the container when it's running, we only have access to `worldserver` console right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) file:

```
 - ${DOCKER_VOL_ETC:-./env/docker/etc}:/azerothcore/env/dist/etc
```

the `etc` directory is located in `env/dist/etc` by default (unless you override it in your `.env` file)

Comment: The ``env/dist/etc/`` folder is empty for me. But the ``env/docker/etc/`` folder has ``worldserver.conf`` file (I didn't change anything in the ``.env`` file)

Comment: @Sedatyf what if you try to put your config files there?

Comment: for docker the default config path is the env/docker/etc folder on the local file system. thats what this part of the yaml file is pointing to: ${DOCKER_VOL_ETC:-./env/docker/etc}